# Is there a commutative binary operation which is closed, has a neutral, unique negatives, satisfies cancellation but not associative?

Tags: group-theory

What I want is:

1. a close operation
2. there's a neutral
3. there're unique negatives
4. cancellation laws
5. commutativity
6. but no associativity

Can I get all this?

Comment: [This table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Classification_by_properties) seems to imply that you want something between a loop and a unital magma. Divisibility is stronger than cancellation laws.

Comment: I assume that by "negatives" you mean inverse elements. Why are you listing cancellation laws in addition to that? The existence of inverses implies cancellation laws.

Comment: @joriki What you said requires associativity.

Comment: @OMGsh: Ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: "Commutative Moufang loops" fulfill the conditions.

Comment: If you relax commutativity, the following provides an example:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
5 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer:
(4 X 3)X2=!4X(3 X 2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4871463.java) that generates all left-cancellative binary operations with identity on up to $6$ elements and checks whether they fulfil the remaining conditions. The result is that there are no such binary operations on less than $6$ elements, and $396$ such operations on $6$ elements, which form $7$ equivalence classes under permutations of the elements:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&4&3&5&2&0\\
2&2&3&0&4&5&1\\
3&3&5&4&1&0&2\\
4&4&2&5&0&1&3\\
5&5&0&1&2&3&4
\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&5&3&4&2&0\\
2&2&3&4&5&0&1\\
3&3&4&5&0&1&2\\
4&4&2&0&1&5&3\\
5&5&0&1&2&3&4
\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&3&4&5&2&0\\
2&2&4&3&0&5&1\\
3&3&5&0&4&1&2\\
4&4&2&5&1&0&3\\
5&5&0&1&2&3&4
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&4&3&5&2&0\\
2&2&3&4&0&5&1\\
3&3&5&0&4&1&2\\
4&4&2&5&1&0&3\\
5&5&0&1&2&3&4
\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&4&3&5&2&0\\
2&2&3&0&4&5&1\\
3&3&5&4&0&1&2\\
4&4&2&5&1&0&3\\
5&5&0&1&2&3&4
\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&4&3&5&0&2\\
2&2&3&0&4&5&1\\
3&3&5&4&1&2&0\\
4&4&0&5&2&1&3\\
5&5&2&1&0&3&4
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
1&1&0&5&2&3&4\\
2&2&5&0&4&1&3\\
3&3&2&4&0&5&1\\
4&4&3&1&5&0&2\\
5&5&4&3&1&2&0
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Your example is obtained from the last of these tables e.g. by swapping $1$ and $3$.